# How can I participate in the discussion of my question if I lost the unregistered account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have asked a question being unregistered, now my account is lost. I would like to participate in the discussion and in particular comment answers (concerning which I have questions)?
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a 12 steps program to help you:

1. Locate questions from all previously used accounts (at least one from every account, in case there are several accounts).
2. Figure out a way to prove that these were your accounts (by email, or something)
3. Send an email to the moderators and request to merge all the accounts, if there is only one account it can just as easily be done via flagging for moderator attention requesting that.
4. Sit back and wait.
5. Have a beer.
6. Take a nap.
7. Eat something.
8. Take a walk outside.
9. Come back home.
10. Check your email/flag history.
11. If there is no change and no reply, repeat from step 4. Otherwise continue.
12. If there is a negative reply, deal with it. Otherwise everything is done, huzzah.

Comment: Where's the PROFIT! there? ;)

Comment: @J.M.: I actually wrote "send me a case of whisky" at the end of step 12; but then I thought to myself... I should go to sleep.

Comment: Flagging would work for multiple accounts, too. The "contact us" email at the bottom of the page doesn't go to moderators, and although we employees *can* merge accounts too... it's easier/faster to just raise a flag for a mod. :)